# how to use a model function in scope in laravel?

Tags: laravel, scope

I have two tables

1- Products

2- Discounts

I want to select all discounted products, but there is a problem, in Discount table there is no product_id, there is array of product id like : ["1","4","23"] which means this discount is used for products with id of 1 or 4 or 23.

I already created a function in my product model that defines if the product has discount or not and use it like :

`$product->hasDiscount(); //returns 1 or 0`

what I need actually?

I need an scope for my product model like below to use in my select query to get all discounted products:

```
public function scopeDiscounted($query)
{
return $query->where($this->hasDiscount() , '=' , 1); 
// I know this code is wrong, I just want to explain the needed code result
}
```

Comment: Your data is not normalized and you should fix that, keeping ids in a json column is bad practice.

Comment: so if we assume data is normalized, how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: I can write up an answer later tonight also a plan to normalize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start by normalizing your data, create the following table and loop in a migration.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('discount_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('discount_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('product_id');

        // add foreign keys if you like
    });

    Discount::all()->each(function (Discount $discount) {
        $productIds = json_encode($discount->productIds);
    
        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            $discount->saveMany(Product::whereIn('id', $productIds)->get());
        }
    });
}
```

To make this migration work, you have to create the relationships before running the migration. I was lazy using models in the migration, the best approach is to use the DB facade.

```
class Discount {
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}


class Product {
    public function discounts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Discount::class);
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to get all discounted products and you could put this in your scope.

```
$discountedProducts = Product::whereHas('discounts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('active', true);
    $query->whereDate('expire_at', '>=', now())
})->get();
```

Comment: is it possible to check if discount is active or not, or for example expired or not?

Comment: Updated the example :)